# how to solve this account problem?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

Friends. I did a stupid thing here and need your help.
I just want to delete the accounts, so I delete everything in datadir, the datadir is the directory which is used in the command below:

```
./geth --datadir ethereum init genesis.json
```

After deleting, I run the command ./geth --datadir ethereum init genesis.json

```
> eth.accounts
["0x6d0b5524a7cfd667a4f7ce5744c15ad31588ded4"]
```

but when I run command below:

```
superman@ubuntu:~/data/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum$ ./geth account list
Account #0: {9aed02c60c71ea53e7d34f52c624ab060b467b84} keystore:///home/superman/.ethereum/keystore/UTC--2017-06-16T02-26-03.490121281Z--9aed02c60c71ea53e7d34f52c624ab060b467b84
Account #1: {acf3e3d535903e8ddeefc25cfc9a9fcec74cf60f} keystore:///home/superman/.ethereum/keystore/UTC--2017-07-20T03-04-30.295140884Z--acf3e3d535903e8ddeefc25cfc9a9fcec74cf60f
```

why it shows 2 accounts but there is only 1 account in geth console? And there are not same? how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `--datadir ethereum` in the first two commands, but not in the last one. The last command uses the default `--datadir` of `.ethereum`. Thus, you see the keystore's location is `/home/superman/.ethereum`. There must be two accounts in the `/home/superman/.ethereum` directory. If you want to use the `ethereum` directory for storing data, the last command should be

```
./geth --datadir ethereum account list
```